Does dating the Ramayana to 5114 bc contradict deeply held beliefs of Hinduism?
The fanatically and relentlessly sectarian Srivaishnavite preacher Dushyant Sridar who gives talks on Sriviashnavism and calls them talks on Hinduism has become a celebrity - and is universally dubbed a "Vedic Scholar" by laypersons like Arnab Goswami.
He has published a book on Ramayana in which he has lent support to the 5114 bc date for Rama's birth.
This has given rise to a furor among other Vaishnavites, as below:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-SyfWfeclzY
These two religious scholars are claiming that dating the Ramayana according to the Western calendar amounts to an assault on Hindu Shastra and is a "Dosha" दोष which has meanings like badness, wickedness, sinfulness offence, transgression, guilt, crime.
They called Dushyant's acharya who has said he doesn't agree with Dushyant.
How does a 5514 b.c date for Rama's birth contradict Hindu Shastra?

Nowhere mentioned in the ramayana that it happened in Treta Yuga let alone 24th Treta Yuga. For that we need to look at Mahabharata and Puranas. If so, why not we look at slokas from Mahabharata and interpret the phrase rama ruled for 11000 years as allegorical

I think that the scholars mentioned in the Youtube video are over-reacting. While using the Western calendar to determine dates of Hindu festivals is indeed a transgression, the same can't be said for cross-dating events.
